# Puxar dadados API Rest e exibir na tela os dados

Tags: jquery, web-service, rest

Consigo fazer um ajax para o serviço e retornar os dados, consigo exibir o primeiro objeto **Product** e suas propriedades, mas quando tem outro objeto dentro ProductImage que possua mais de 5 objetos dentro, eu não consigo exibir os dados deles

```
$.getJSON("http://www.dipes.com.br/web_api/products/9751/", function(data) {

            console.log(data);
            console.log(data.Product.name);

            var output="<ul>";
            for (var i in data.Product.ProductImage) 
            {
                output+="<li>" + data.Product.ProductImage.i.http  + "</li>";
            }
            output+="</ul>";

            $('span').html(output);
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O código está errado. A forma correta de mostrar o array dentro do objeto seria:

```
output+="<li>" + data.Product.ProductImage[i].http  + "</li>";
```

Comment: Fala André,
Eu já fiz isso anteriormente... e o erro continuava, o erro é esse:

html5.html:72 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [

No console ele mostra que o erro é no [.



Para você ter noção, eu coloquei o indice na mão e ainda dá erro.

ex: console.log(data.Product.ProductImage.1.http);

Comment: console.log(data.Product.ProductImage.1.http); vai dar erro, tem que ser console.log(data.Product.ProductImage[1].http); Testei aqui e não deu erro nenhum.

Comment: Esse é o codigo que estou usando:



  $.getJSON("http://www.dipes.com.br/web_api/products/9751/", function(data) {

   console.log(data);
      console.log(data.Product.name);

      console.log(data.Product.ProductImage.[1].http);


      var output="<ul>";
            for (var i in data.Product.ProductImage) 
            {
                output+="<li>" + data.Product.ProductImage.[i].http  + "</li>";
            }
            output+="</ul>";
            
            $('span').html(output);

  });


Erro: Unexpected token [

Comment: Vc colocou "." a mais. vc colocou "console.log(data.Product.ProductImage.[1].http);" o correto é "console.log(data.Product.ProductImage[1].http);" . Depois do ProductImage não tem ponto

Comment: Exato!!!
Erro idiota, me desculpe!

Obrigado pela ajuda!